# Render not waiting for data request

Tags: reactjs

Not sure why, but my render doesn't seem to be waiting for `componentDidMount` to finish its request before rendering. I have another component where it does. I'm not sure where I'm messing up.

**Broken:**

```
componentDidMount() {
    if(this.isMounted()) {
        $.get('/filter/parameters')
            .done(parameters => {
                this.setState({parameters});
            })
            .fail(err => {console.error(err)});
    }
}

<SideNav parameters={this.state.parameters}
        selectedFilters={this.state.selectedFilters} 
        isOpen={this._isOpen}
        onProductChange={this._handleProductsChange} />
```

**Working:**

```
componentDidMount() {
    if(this.isMounted()) {
        $.get('/getPartLocal')
            .done(data => {
                this.setState({data: data})})
            .fail(err => console.error(err));
    }
}

<TestTable data={this.state.data}
        onHeaderClick={this.sortColumn}
        onRowSelect={this.updateSelectedRows} />
```

**UPDATE**

So now that it's passing through I have a new problem:

I can't set an attribute:

```
<DropDownMenu value={parameters.products[0].name} onChange={onProductChange}>
```

But I *can* map:

```
{parameters.products.map(obj => {
       return <MenuItem value={obj.name} primaryText={obj.name}/>
})}
```

Why?

Comment: What error are you getting for the first component?

Comment: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined